# jQuery keeps the last click and sends more data

Tags: php, jquery

Can somebody tell me why every time I click on a button where I have a jQuery post function, it sends twice the post, and the next time I press the button, it will send twice as much as the last time and so on? I searched on Google and I found `unbind()` but it is not working so well, and I don't know what to search on Google for solving this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("includes/document.php",
    function(data) {
      $("#body").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

The html:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="name">
        <p>Username </p>
        <input id="nameInput" type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="button">Press Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `#button` element within a form?

Comment: no,there are simple input text fields

Comment: Can you post the html to provide a little more context?

Comment: How do you know that handler is executed twice?

Comment: <div id="body">
 <div id="name">
  <p>Username </p><input id="nameInput" type="text">
 </div>
 <div id="button">Press Me</div>
</div>

Comment: i use firebug and it appears on console,not only twice,every time is doubling

Comment: i can use $(document).one('click',function(){}) and is working but this isnt my only button

Comment: its not `$(document).one('click',function(){})` , its `$(document).on('click',function(){})`, right?

Comment: what is data your getting from your response

Answer (score 1):

Why not use live.

```
$(function(){
  $("#button").live("click",function(){
    $.post("includes/document.php",
    function(data) {
      $("#body").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Jquery.live handles event delegation and removes any ghost event listeners attached to previously rendered elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't binding more than one `click` event to the `div#button`, double check that you haven't included your jQuery more than once in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    // Your code...
    $.post();

    // just add return false here
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Many time I also faced same request.

First Unbind the event and then bind it again.

you can do following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){

    $.post("includes/document.php",
            function(data) {
              $("#body").html(data);
            });

    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if placing button outside  the #body div solves the problem....